# activity_main looks completely different

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, layout

I a following this course on Pluralsight:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/getting-started-android-development/table-of-contents
and when I create my project with the "Basic Activity", My activity_main looks completely different than his. The first one is mine and the second one is his:
[image: Mine]
[image: His]
He only has a constraint layout with a Text view, but I have a coordinator layout and a app bar layout and a toolbar and all this stuff which I don't know. I haven't changed mine a bit. I am not able to post anything else from the video because of piracy, but I can give you more info on my project if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various default project templates get tweaked and modified from time to time. When they added the Navigation framework, they put into this blank project a basic example of its usage to swap between two fragments with a button.

I think if you do the following, it will get you pretty close to the starting project in the video:

Replace the contents of `res/values/strings.xml` with this:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world</string>
</resources>
```

Delete the file in the `res/navigation` directory.

Delete the files `fragment_first.xml` and `fragment_second.xml` in the `res/layout` directory.

Replace the contents of `content_main.xml` with the following. You can switch to the code editor by pressing the Code button in the top right corner.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And don't worry about the preview no longer showing the simulated navigation bar and status bar of the device. That won't affect what you're doing.

Comment: Wow! That is the most detailed answer I have ever seen! Thank you so much!